# NSPredicate aggregate function [SIZE] gives 'unsupported function expression' error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, aggregate, nspredicate

iOS 4:
I have entities in Core Data (using SQLite, which is a requirement) of:

- Request
- Response (which has a property personId)
- Revision

Relationships are:

- Request <-->> Revision
- Request <-->> Response
- Revision <--> Response

(e.g. each request may have many responses; each request/response pair may have many revisions)

I'm trying to do a predicate to get all Responses with a given personId that have zero Revisions.

Using:

```
(personId == %d) && (Request.Revision[SIZE] == 0)
```

in my predicate string gives me a runtime exception "Unsupported function expression Request.Revision[SIZE]"

The documentation seems pretty sparse on aggregate functions, only noting that they exist, but with no syntax or examples.  Not sure if it's my syntax or if the SIZE function really isn't supported in iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
(personId == %d) && (Request.Revision.@count == 0)
```

Comment: I seem to remember having read something about performance being different between [SIZE] and @count, but it seems to me like with Core Data since the business end of a to-many relationship is just a set of pointers that performance would be equivalent in both cases (e.g. neither one faults the referenced objects into memory).  Does that sound right?

Comment: P.S. still interested in whether the [SIZE] agg. function is supported in iOS.

Comment: I'm beginning increasingly respect CoreData with Predicate feature ). Thanks Dave for giving a clue regarding @count syntax